# Limit the retrieve of documents from Firebase on Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, limit

I would like to learn how can I limit the retrieved document from Firestore quantity for each user. Is there any possible way to achieve this with shared preferences? Because I do not use a login or registration protocol for the user. I am using shared preferences in order to recognize the user.

Single user should retrieve only 1 document each day. This is what I want to implement.

Also I would like to learn that how can I save and show fetching date of the document?

Comment: You can't restrict the count of retrieval from the firebase side. If it's strictly associated with the device then using the device storage (Shared preference) it the best option.

Comment: Could you please share a document,code or link in order to achive this?

Comment: I didn't find any document related to this. But, Simply you can keep track of retrieval event in the device storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following in Firebase:

```
Query query = cities.orderBy("name").limit(3); // descending order

Query query = cities.whereGreaterThan("population", 2500000L).orderBy("population").limit(2); // ascending order
```

You can take a look at the documentation, there are the corresponding methods.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Comment: How can I add date of retrieve the data and store it with sharedpreferences?

Comment: You have it in the same flutter documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value

Comment: ı do not allow to retrieve same user same document this is the issue...

Comment: You must use an id, for example if you want to read the details of a single record you can pass the id of the record through a url to the .html details view of the record and there compare the ids, Firebase usually creates a key automatically, you can use that key, in this Post I explain how to do it with jQuery:  https://blog.nubecolectiva.com/como-crear-un-crud-con-firebase-7-14-2-y-bootstrap-4-parte-4/